# Horizontal printing and scaling in python

Tags: python

I'm only new to Python, I'm trying to create a little program that prints the letters of a word if it is a valid input.

What I have currently only prints the letters vertically. I would like to print them horizontally with a space between the letters.
I would also like to make the output scalable. It is currently in a 7x7 but I can't wrap my head around how to add a variable to make it an 8x8 or 5x5 with the letters hopefully still displaying correctly.

What would be the best way to perhaps combine valid letter outputs?

I'm using Jupyter Notebook 6.5.4. This is what I have so far.

```
def is_valid_word(word):
    # Check if the word contains only valid letters
    valid_letters = set("ABNOTY")
    return all(letter in valid_letters for letter in word)

def main():
    while True:
        word = input("Enter a valid word (or 'END' to stop): ")
        
        if word.upper() == "END":
            break
        
        if not is_valid_word(word):
            print("Error: Invalid input. Please enter a valid word.")
            continue
       
        for letter in word:
            if letter == 'T':
                print(" *******\n    *    \n    *    \n    *     \n    *    \n    *    ", end="  ")
            elif letter == 'O':
                print("   ***  \n  *   * \n *     *\n *     *\n *     *\n  *   * \n   ***  ", end="  ")
            elif letter == 'Y':
                print(" *     *\n  *   * \n   * *  \n    *   \n    *   \n    *   \n    *   ", end="  ")
            elif letter == 'N':
                print(" *     *\n **    *\n * *   *\n *  *  *\n *   * *\n *    **\n *     *", end="  ")
            elif letter == 'B':
                print(" ****** \n *     *\n *     *\n ****** \n *     *\n *     *\n ****** ", end="  ")
            elif letter == 'A':
                print("    *   \n   * *  \n  *   * \n *******\n *     *\n *     *\n *     *", end="  ")
            print()       
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am not allowed to use multiline strings.

Comment: I think youre looking for [Escape Sequences](https://www.ibm.com/docs/ko/zos/2.4.0?topic=set-escape-sequences)

Comment: The empty `print()` there at the end explicitly outputs a newline, making the output "vertical"…!?

Comment: For each letter you need a list of strings, one string for each row of it. Then loop through the rows and for each row loop through the letters to print and combine the strings of the row of the letters and print the row.

Comment: @PatioFurnitureIsCool I thank you for your response! I have edited my question, I do apologise if I have wasted your time. The question was edited to include that I'm not allowed to use multiline strings. Again I apologise!

Comment: Thank you also to everyone else who has offered suggestions!

Comment: @Paul no worries, I just updated answer with no multiline

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I padded white space for scaling. May be OP can update question if they need stars to be added to scaled up letters as well.*

*Note: 7x7 grid is minimum requirements for letters. You can't make 7x7 to 5x5 without losing data i.e letter shape. So scale down makes no sense*.

Update: OP mentioned they were not allowed to use multiline strings

You can try:

```py
import re

def is_valid_word(word):
    # Check if the word contains only valid letters
    valid_letters = set("ABNOTY")
    return all(letter in valid_letters for letter in word)


def scale_letters(let, by=1):
    if by < 1:
        return let
    spaces = by * ' '
    new_lines = by * '\n'
    return new_lines.join([re.sub('', spaces, i) for i in let.split('\n')])


def horizontal_me(output, scale_factor=1):
    hor_out = []
    for k in range(len(output)):
        hor_out.append([j + " " for j in output[k].split('\n') if j])
    out = ''
    for l in range(len(hor_out[0])):
        for j in range(len(hor_out)):
            out += ''.join(hor_out[j][l])
        print(scale_letters(out, scale_factor))
        out = ''


def main(horizontal=False, scale_factor=1):
    output = []
    while True:

        word = input("Enter a valid word (or 'END' to stop): ")

        if word.upper() == "END":
            break

        if not is_valid_word(word):
            print("Error: Invalid input. Please enter a valid word.")
            continue

        print()
        for letter in word:
            if letter == 'T':
                output.append(" *******\n    *    \n    *    \n    *     \n    *    \n    *    \n    *    ")

            elif letter == 'O':
                output.append("   ***  \n  *   * \n *     *\n *     *\n *     *\n  *   * \n   ***  ")

            elif letter == 'Y':
                output.append(" *     *\n *   * \n  * *  \n  *   \n   *   \n   *   \n   *   \n    *    ")

            elif letter == 'N':
                output.append(" *     *\n **    *\n * *   *\n *  *  *\n *   * *\n *    **\n *     *")

            elif letter == 'B':
                output.append(" ****** \n *     *\n *     *\n ****** \n *     *\n *     *\n ****** ")

            elif letter == 'A':
                output.append("    *   \n   * *  \n  *   * \n *******\n *     *\n *     *\n *     *")

        if horizontal:
            horizontal_me(output, scale_factor)
        else:
            new_lines = "\n" * scale_factor
            print(new_lines.join([scale_letters(i, scale_factor) for i in output]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(horizontal=True, scale_factor=4)
```

Output:

`scale_factor=default (1)`:

```
Enter a valid word (or 'END' to stop): ABNOTY

       *         * * * * * *     *           *       * * *       * * * * * * *   *           *   
     *   *       *           *   * *         *     *       *           *           *       *     
   *       *     *           *   *   *       *   *           *         *             *   *       
 * * * * * * *   * * * * * *     *     *     *   *           *         *               *         
 *           *   *           *   *       *   *   *           *         *               *         
 *           *   *           *   *         * *     *       *           *               *         
 *           *   * * * * * *     *           *       * * *             *               *
```

`scale_factor=3`:

```
Enter a valid word (or 'END' to stop): ABNOTY

               *                   *   *   *   *   *   *           *                       *               *   *   *               *   *   *   *   *   *   *       *                       *       
           *       *               *                       *       *   *                   *           *               *                       *                       *               *           
       *               *           *                       *       *       *               *       *                       *                   *                           *       *               
   *   *   *   *   *   *   *       *   *   *   *   *   *           *           *           *       *                       *                   *                               *                   
   *                       *       *                       *       *               *       *       *                       *                   *                               *                   
   *                       *       *                       *       *                   *   *           *               *                       *                               *                   
   *                       *       *   *   *   *   *   *           *                       *               *   *   *                           *                               *
```